# Trying to build a helloworld.c program on Visual studio but keep getting fatal error?

Tags: c, visual-studio, cygwin, fatal-error

```
> Executing task: gcc -g o helloworld helloworld.c <

cc1: fatal error: helloworld.c: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
The terminal process "C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe '--login', '-c', 'gcc -g o helloworld 

helloworld.c'" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

Comment: Did you save the file?

Comment: yeah its saved as helloworld.c

Comment: `gcc -g o helloworld helloworld.c` is not executed in the same folder as `helloworld.c`

Comment: `code`   "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build hello world",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "gcc",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "o",
                "helloworld",
                "helloworld.c"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build", 
                "isDefault": true

Comment: This is the code I have in task.json, is something incorrect?

Comment: Can you open an interactive bash from within Visual studio and run gcc from there?

Comment: Try `gcc -g -o helloworld helloworld.c`